# Interseção de vetores em C

Tags: c

No código abaixo a intenção é fazer a interseção de dois vetores, porem quando ele não verifica se o valor for `0` nesse trecho

```
if(vet1[i] == vet2[j]) 
{
    n = vet1[i];
}else
{
    C[i] = '\0'; 
}
```

Eu verifico se os valores são iguais para a interseção, mas quando chego no `printf`

```
for(int i=0; i < 5;i++)
{
    if(C[i] != '\0')
    printf("os dois vetores tem em comum %d.\n", C[i]);
}
```

Como faço para verificar que há uma interseção do numero `0` ?
Utilizei o `\0` pra que quando não haja uma interseção ele aderir um valor nulo.

Código inteiro abaixo:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
    int n;
    int vet1[5]= {1,8,9,4,5}, vet2[8] = {8,3,6,5,4,3,2,1}, C[5];
    
    for(int i=0; i < 5;i++)
    {
        n=0;
        for(int j=0;j < 8;j++)
        {
            // verifica se na posiçao i o vetor é 
            if(vet1[i] == vet2[j])
            {
                n = vet1[i];
            }else
            {
                C[i] = '\0'; 
            }
        }
        C[i] = n;

    }
    for(int i=0; i < 5;i++)
    {
        if(C[i] != '\0')
        printf("os dois vetores tem em comum %d.\n", C[i]);
    }
    for
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema na solução que tem refere-se com a lógica e ao valor "nulo".
Não existe valor nulo para inteiro, e `\0` é incorreto também porque é um `char` e apenas tem aplicação em strings. Acontece que o compilador vai lhe permitir fazer isso mas vai colocar um zero normal. Então seria o mesmo que fazer `C[i] = 0`. Isso também não está correto pois pode ter intersecção com o valor 0, e depois não consegue distinguir se é valor válido ou "nulo".

A solução é controlar o tamanho do vetor de intersecção e ir aumentando cada vez que percebe que um elemento existe nos dois vetores. Assim tem a certeza que só tem valores válidos no vetor

Solução:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int vet1[5]= {1,8,9,4,5}, vet2[8] = {8,3,6,5,4,3,2,1}, C[5];
    int tamC = 0; //novo tamanho para o vetor C

    for(int i=0; i < 5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j < 8;j++)
        {
            if(vet1[i] == vet2[j])
            {
                C[tamC] = vet1[i]; //coloca o elemento no vetor de interseccao
                tamC++; //aumenta a quantidade no vetor de interseccao
                break; //termina a procura
            }
            //sem else
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i < tamC;i++) //percorre até ao tamC
    {
        std::cout << "os dois vetores tem em comum " << C[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comentei no código todos os ajustes que fiz.

A lógica dentro do `if` que regista o valor no vetor de interseção poderia ser mais resumida, guardando o valor e incrementando simultaneamente:

```
if(vet1[i] == vet2[j])
{
    C[tamC++] = vet1[i]; // <--
    break;
}
```

Mas optei por deixar na forma mais extensa para ser mais clara, e não gerar qualquer confusão mesmo a principiantes.

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/VZi51H)